# How to run build after install in webpack library

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have this library https://github.com/dhilst/webpacklibraryexample

I can install it by `yarn add git+https://github.com/dhilst/webpacklibraryexample.git` but it wont build (run webpack) after install. I expect that dist/ folder is present after the installation finishes.

If I try to use I got an `Cannot find module` error. What I'm doing wrong?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got this. You need the *prepare* instead of *build* as in docs:

> If the package being installed contains a prepare script, its dependencies and devDependencies will be installed, and the prepare script will be run, before the package is packaged and installed.

Also *webpack-cli* was missing at *devDependencies*.